sls deploy for azure gives error AWS credentials missing
I have created a serverless application following https://github.com/serverless/serverless-azure-functions?tab=readme-ov-file#create-a-new-azure-function-app steps.
running command: sls create -t azure-python -p <appName> gives error Configuration file not found in directory "/Users/<path>/z-serverless". I have created a serverless.yml file with dummy data, and then running the same command gives error:
✖ AWS credentials missing or invalid. Run "serverless" to set up AWS credentials, or learn more in our docs: http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup.


I am getting this error running any serverless command.
Below is the content of the serverless.yml file:
# "org" ensures this Service is used with the correct Serverless Framework Access Key.
org: t
# "app" enables Serverless Framework Dashboard features and sharing them with other Services.
app: z-serverless
service: azure-serverless
useDotenv: true

provider:
  name: azure
  region: westus
  runtime: python3.8 # python3.7 or python3.8 also available
  os: linux  # linux is the only operating system available for python
  subscriptionId: <subscriptionId>

plugins: # look for additional plugins in the community plugins repo: https://github.com/serverless/plugins
  - serverless-azure-functions
  - serverless-dotenv-plugin

# you can add packaging information here
package:
  patterns:
    - '!env/**'
    - '!.env/**'
    - '!local.settings.json'
    - '!.vscode/**'
    - '!__pycache__/**'
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - '!.python_packages/**'
    - '!.funcignore'
    - '!package.json'
    - '!package-lock.json'
    - '!.gitignore'
    - '!.git/**'
  exclude:
    - local.settings.json
    - .vscode/**


Not sure why it is looking for AWS credentials when I have used azure everywhere.

I have found the issue of why it is only looking for AWS credentials.
The latest serverless versions do not support Azure and only work for AWS.
I had to downgrade my serverless version to make it work.
npm uninstall serverless -g 
npm install -g serverless@2.35.0

Not sure, why the support for Azure was removed from serverless, and should I stop working with Azure serverless, in case serverless won't work anymore with azure?
